# A Kleinian group has the same limit set as its normal subgroups'

Tags: reference-request, hyperbolic-geometry, geometric-group-theory

It should be well known that a Kleinian group and all its normal (non-elementary) subgroups have the same limit set. Do you know any book/article where I could find the proof?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You should have a look at Thurston's notes:

http://library.msri.org/books/gt3m/PDF/

corollary 8.1.3 on page 172.