# Find an example of an infinitely generated discrete subgroup of ${\rm SL}(2,\Bbb R)$.

Tags: topological-groups

I want to find an example of an infinitely generated discrete subgroup of ${\rm SL}(2,\Bbb R)$ but I haven't managed to find such a subgroup.

Please would someone help me to find such subgroup?

Comment: (Optional) hint: there exist finitely generated groups with infinitely generated subgroups

Comment: I am sure this was asked earlier.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1986435/kernel-of-an-epimorphism-form-a-surface-group-to-a-free-group/2025749#2025749